# How to make eBPF program sleepable

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ebpf, bpf, libbpf

I've been reading about sleepable eBPF programs, specifically [this article](https://lwn.net/Articles/825415/) provides a nice introduction. However I am struggling to find any documentation or examples on how to actually achieve this in code. Any tips or links to documentation are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**note**: This answer was last updated 29-03-2023, sleepable programs are still subject to change, this answer might not be accurate past kernel v6.3.

As of the writing of this answer, no official documentation for this feature exists. The closest you can get at this moment is the LWN article and the [commit messages](https://lore.kernel.org/netdev/20200827220114.69225-3-alexei.starovoitov@gmail.com/).

Sleepable programs were added in v5.10.

eBPF programs that are "sleepable" cannot actually actively sleep like a userspace program can (e.g. "os.sleep(100ms)"). It is a property which allows the program to call certain helper functions which are otherwise not available. For example `bpf_copy_from_user`.

Non-sleepable eBPF programs are guaranteed to not switch between CPUs and on non RT (Real Time) kernels will not be interrupted by the scheduler. However, some operations like reading from userspace memory might be IO bound, if that userspace memory is file-backed for example. So these functions might "sleep" or block until that IO is done. It makes sense for the kernel to do something else in the mean time. Which is why this was introduced.

This has some implications:

> The non-sleepable programs are relying on implicit rcu_read_lock() and
> migrate_disable() to protect life time of programs, maps that they use and
> per-cpu kernel structures used to pass info between bpf programs and the
> kernel. The sleepable programs cannot be enclosed into rcu_read_lock().
> migrate_disable() maps to preempt_disable() in non-RT kernels, so the progs
> should not be enclosed in migrate_disable() as well. Therefore
> rcu_read_lock_trace is used to protect the life time of sleepable progs.

To load a program as sleepable, the `BPF_F_SLEEPABLE` flag has to be passed to the `BPF_PROG_LOAD` syscall command. For authors using libbpf, the easiest way to tell the loader to do so is to add a `.s` to the end of the program section. For an LSM hook on file_protect the section name would become `lsm.s/file_protect` a uprobe for example `uprobe.s//proc/self/exe:trigger_func3`

In v5.10 only fentry/fexit/fmod_ret and lsm programs can be sleepable. Even so, not all LSM hooks are allowed to be sleepable. The patch set adds a special list of sleepable hooks:

```c
/* non exhaustive list of sleepable bpf_lsm_*() functions */
BTF_SET_START(btf_sleepable_lsm_hooks)
#ifdef CONFIG_BPF_LSM
BTF_ID(func, bpf_lsm_file_mprotect)
BTF_ID(func, bpf_lsm_bprm_committed_creds)
#endif
BTF_SET_END(btf_sleepable_lsm_hooks)

static int check_sleepable_lsm_hook(u32 btf_id)
{
    return btf_id_set_contains(&btf_sleepable_lsm_hooks, btf_id);
}
```

In v5.18 support for sleepable iterator programs has been added in [this patch set](https://lore.kernel.org/all/20220124185403.468466-1-kennyyu@fb.com/).

In v6.0 support for sleepable uprobes and uretprobes was added in [this patch set](https://lore.kernel.org/all/cover.1655248075.git.delyank@fb.com/).

In v6.3 support for sleepable sockops programs was added in [this patch set](https://lore.kernel.org/all/20230125164735.785732-1-void@manifault.com/).

Lastly in v5.10, sleepable programs are only allowed to use pre-allocated `BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH`, `BPF_MAP_TYPE_LRU_HASH` and `BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY` maps.

In v5.12, [this patch](https://lore.kernel.org/bpf/20210210033634.62081-9-alexei.starovoitov@gmail.com/), allows sleepable programs to use per-CPU map types: `BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERCPU_HASH`, `BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERCPU_ARRAY`, `BPF_MAP_TYPE_LRU_PERCPU_HASH`, `BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY_OF_MAPS`, and `BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH_OF_MAPS`

In v5.12, [this patch set](https://lore.kernel.org/bpf/20210204193622.3367275-1-kpsingh@kernel.org/), allows sleepable programs to use ringbuffers: `BPF_MAP_TYPE_RINGBUF`

In v5.17, [this patch set](https://lore.kernel.org/bpf/20211224152916.1550677-1-kpsingh@kernel.org/), allows sleepable programs to use storage maps: `BPF_MAP_TYPE_INODE_STORAGE`, `BPF_MAP_TYPE_SK_STORAGE`, and `BPF_MAP_TYPE_TASK_STORAGE`

When user ring buffers were introduced in v6.1, in [this patch set](https://lore.kernel.org/bpf/20220920000100.477320-1-void@manifault.com/), sleepable programs got access to `BPF_MAP_TYPE_USER_RINGBUF` as well.

And in v6.2, [this patch set](https://lore.kernel.org/all/20221201050444.2785007-1-yhs@fb.com/), gave sleepable programs access to `BPF_MAP_TYPE_CGRP_STORAGE`.

Comment: Thanks for a thorough response. My goal is to read data from an nignx process. Doing so with atomic bpf functions fails with -EFAULT and retrieves only gibberish. EFAULT (from bpf_read_from_user) indicates a page fault, I believe, which I'd like to wait for with a sleepable bpf program.

Now, doing `grep BPF_F_SLEEPABLE libbpf.c` provides several more SEC definitions than only  fentry/fexit/fmod_ret, like uprobes, kprobes and some tp if I recall correctly.

Comment: Over to the practical side my understanding is that this flag (`BPF_F_SLEEPABLE`) should be set prior to loading the program, but seem to find little information on how to do so. I cannot seem to find any tests that might demonstrate this in the commit.

Comment: You are right, I only covered the initial addition of sleepable programs, I have updated the answer with all of the history I could find since, related to sleepable programs. Also added a section on how to make a program as sleepable.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look through these and see if I am able to find out how to implement it. Out of curiosity, did you find all these by googling or were you aware of them beforehand?

Comment: And additionally to my use case, I've been experimenting with bpftrace. I find it very curious that bpftrace is indeed able to retrieve nginx information (with plain scripts), while libbpf scripts return `-EFAULT`. That leads me to believe that either my assumption that `-EFAULT` occurs due to the page fault is wrong, or bpftrace somehow implements sleepable programs.  In the latter case, it seems like it would be so by default, which seems unusual. Do you have any insights in this? Or where to start finding out?

Comment: I can't say what the cause of the error might be based on that limited info. I would suggest you open a new question and include details such as the source code that is throwing errors and a reference to the bpftrace script.